# How does non-magical healing work in AD&D 2nd Edition?

Tags: house-rules, adnd-2e, healing

I'm unclear on how natural non-magical healing is supposed to work in AD&D 2nd Edition. In the Dungeon Master Guide, Chapter 9 : Combat, in the section titled "Natural Healing" it states :

> Characters heal naturally at a rate of *1 hit point per day of rest*. Rest is defined as low activity - nothing more strenuous than riding a horse or traveling from one place to another.

It goes on to state :

> If a character has complete bed-rest (doing nothing for an entire day), he can regain *3 hit points for that day*.

This makes sense.

However in the Player's Handbook, Chapter 5 : Proficiencies, under the non-weapon proficiency "Healing" it states :

> If a wounded character remains under the care of someone with healing proficiency, that character can recover lost hit points at the rate of *1 per day* even when traveling or engaging in nonstrenuous activity.

It goes on to state :

> If the wounded character gets complete rest, he can recover *2 hit points per day* while under such care. Only characters with both healing and hebalism proficiencies can help others recover at the rate of *3 hit points per day* of rest.

- Is the idea that if you choose to play with the optional non-weapon proficiencies rules, the natural healing described in the DMG no long applies and the only way to heal naturally is with the help of someone skilled in healing or healing and herablism?
- Is this merely a mistake in the game? If so, are there any errata out there that correct it?
- Does anyone have house rules that override this confusingness?

Side note : 1st Edition also has the 1HP/day rules for a resting character. 3rd Edition has characters healing naturally at the characters level in HP/day and has the "Heal" Skill which doubles the natural healing rate to (2 x Level) HP/day.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like [Steve Winter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Winter) has weighed in [here](http://www.dragonsfoot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=40102&view=next#p824134) that what happens is that the values stack, meaning :

- With no rest (fighting, casting) : 0HP/day
- With rest (traveling allowed) but no help from a healer : 1HP/day
- With rest (traveling allowed) and help from a healer : 2HP/day
- With bed rest (no traveling) but no help from a healer : 3HP/day
- With bed rest (no traveling) and help from a healer : 5HP/day
- With bed rest (no traveling) and help from someone that is both a healer and an herbalist : 6HP/day